# Python, recognizing and handling events with win32 api

Tags: python, winapi, pywin32

My goal is to record mouse position on screen and then replay it. I found the part for creating mouse events easily, but couldn't find anything about recognizing and handling events. Or at least I couldn't find anything that was simple enough for me to understand and use.

So the question is, how can i recognize mouse clicks and handle them?

Comment: Have a look at this question, it's quite similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244317/using-pyhook-to-get-mouse-coordinates-to-play-back-later

Comment: Use [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) for recording and [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx) for playback. The question linked to in the comment above is useless: It requires that the controlled application is the foreground application. And it uses the wrong API to fake mouse input.